# Generic props type arrow

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, lambda

I am quite a bit confused by the "behind the scenes" of the following syntax
`const MyComponent: FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({history}) => { };`
I have seen many such examples and understand that it sets the `FC<RouteComponentProp>` type on the props object passed into the `MyComponent`.

I am, however, confused - can I obtain the same logical outcome of the props type with a different syntax?
Can i write something like -

`const MyComponent = (FC<RouteComponentProps>:{}) => {}`.

Kindly thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the definition of FC or FunctionComponent:

```
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
  (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement | null;
  propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
  contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
  defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
  displayName?: string;
}
```

So if the only thing you cared about was the props and the return type, you could replicated it like this:

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

// ...

const MyComponent = (props: PropsWithChildren<RouteComponentProps>): ReactElement | null => {

}
```

PropsWithChildren is a helper type that adds in the standard react prop `children`, which all components are allowed to take. `PropsWithChildren<RouteComponentProps>` is the same as `RouteComponentProps & { children?: ReactNode }`

---

But as you saw in the definition for FunctionComponent, there's more going on than just props. Components can have a number of static properties. `propTypes` and `displayName` are used for development and debugging, `contextTypes` is used for the old context api, and `defaultProps` is a way to do default values for props.

You may not use these often, but they're possibilities, and if you ever do want to use them, you'd need to update your type to allow them. Or, just use `FC<RouteComponentProps>` and get it all out of the box.